# How to update the same component with different params in Angular

Tags: angular, parameters, angular-ui-router, router, reload

I've done the [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) from angular. It works perfectly.

Now I want to put the dashboard component in the hero detail view. So it shows me the top of heroes, and after that, the hero detail view.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGDt1.png)

I have a Router link that loads the same component, but with different params. I want to know, what to do so that when I click on any element from the dashboard this one load a different hero.

**This is the code of the hero-detail.component.html**

```
<app-dashboard></app-dashboard>
<div *ngIf="hero">
<h2>{{ hero.name | uppercase }} Details</h2>
        <div><span>id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>
        <div>
          <label>name:
          </label>
                <div><span>name: </span>{{hero.name}}</div>

        </div>
<button (click)="goBack()">go back</button>
<button (click)="save()">save</button>
</div>
```

**hero detail class**

```
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() hero: Hero;
    constructor(

      private route: ActivatedRoute,

      private heroService: HeroService,

      private location: Location
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getHero();
    }

    getHero(): void {
      const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
      this.heroService.getHero(id)
        .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
    }

    goBack(): void {
      this.location.back();
    }
    save(): void {
       this.heroService.updateHero(this.hero)
         .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
     }      
}
```

**The dashboard code**

```
<a *ngFor="let hero of heroes" class="col-1-4" routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}">
    <div class="module hero">
      <h4>{{hero.name}}</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
```

**The router is the same as the tutorial.**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent }
];
```

**A bad solution:**

After research a little i found the possibility to add the *(click)="reloadRoute()"* to the  link, but this one refresh all the page.

```
<a *ngFor="let hero of heroes" class="col-1-4" routerLink="/detail/{{hero.id}}"  (click)="reloadRoute()">
    <div class="module hero">
      <h4>{{hero.name}}</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
```

[**Github**](https://github.com/josuevalrob/tour-of-heroes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the snapshot, subscribe to the params. This is what mine looks like:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
        params => {
            const id = +params['id'];
            this.getProduct(id);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I am trying this, but it doesn't show me anything now: 

    `ngOnInit(): void {
   // const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');   
   // this.taskService.getTask(id)
   //   .subscribe(task => this.task = task);
   this.route.params.subscribe(
       params => {
           const id = +params['id'];
           this.taskService.getTask(id);
       }
   );
 }`

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? If you add a console.log inside the subscribe, are you getting the Id?

Comment: i dont know how, but this work: `this.route.params.subscribe(params => {const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')this.heroService.getHero(id).subscribe(Hero => this.hero = hero);});`